# android cannot find realm gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle, realm

I get this error while building:

```
Failed to sync Gradle project 'myapp'
Error:Could not find io.realm:realm-android:0.88.3.
Required by:
    myapp:app:unspecified

Search in build.gradle files
```

In my project level gradle I have added as:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3"
```

In my module level:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.3'
```

How to fix this error?

Project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3'
    }
}
```

Module level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.3'
    //more dependencies here
}
```

Comment: add that module in your project

Comment: Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of application level build.gradle file.

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

Comment: @M D I have already added

Comment: @Dhamaraj I have already did that

Comment: show both the gradle

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have updated the question with gradle files

Comment: remove this dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.3'
    //more dependencies here
}

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks it worked

Comment: Anyone having a similar issue in 2022, but with v5.1.0 of the realm plugin and likely due to the fact that jcenter is being deprecated?

Comment: @TahoeWolverine yes I am having this same issue.    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
        classpath('io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0') {}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From 0.88 onwards Realm is a plugin, not a compile dependency, so you need to apply the plugin `realm-android` instead. It is also described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Top level build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3"
    }
}
```

App level build file

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

In your case, **your should remove**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.3'
}
```

Comment: Current Latest Version : `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.1"`

Keep watching for latest version : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Hmm updated from 0.84.1 to 1.0.1 plugin, but now Realm cannot be found at all. I have the classpath defined in build.gradle and apply plugin in my module. The module is a library, could that be an issue?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Add the following class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
   //check & update 3.0.0 with latest version
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
}
}
```

Step 2: Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Find Latest versions from https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

[image]